# Does Google Custom Search Still Support XML Output?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I'm attempting to use the Google Custom Search API. According to their documentation, I should be able to pass the parameter output=xml to receive XML output. I add this to my get URL and I still get JSON output. Here are the params I am passing:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_API_KEY&cx=MY_CX&output=xml&q=test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ATOM/XML support was removed a year ago: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Which docs are you looking at?